# Questão com webview, abrir mais de um link fora do app

Tags: android, webview

### Tentei meu definir meu webview para abrir mais de um link, mas n funciona

meu codigo faz com que sites.google abra no webview do app e o restante dos links abram fora(nav do android), quero que o sites.google e photos.google abra no webview do app

```
private class MyWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("sites.google.com")) {
            //abrir no meu webview            AQUI EU GOSTARIA DE ADC OUTRO
            return false;                     LINK PARA ABRIR NO MEU WV
        } else {
            //restante dos links abrir no navegador
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Um exemplo

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("sites.google.com") && ("photos.google.com")) {
```

mas isso não funciona, tem como fazer isso? se sim alguem sabe uma outra forma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Minha Solução

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("sites.google.com")) {
            //open url contents in webview
            return false;
        }if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("photos.google.com")) {
            //open url contents in webview
            return false;
    } else {
            //here open external links in external browser or app
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Se alguem tiver outra solução gostaria de ver.